# исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. currentPtr было 0xCCCCCCCC. -- Где ошибка в коде?

Tags: c++, c, список

Пробую писать структуру данных "список" в Visual Studio. Точнее говоря, функцию **insert** (вставка элемента).
По условию моей задачи в узле списка лежат 1) коэффициент при x, 2) степень при x. Новые элементы располагаю в списке по убыванию степени. (понимаю кстати, что можно и лучше было вынести в отдельную структуру power и coefficient и не заставлять ими ListNode):

```
struct ListNode {
    int power; /* степень при х */
    int coefficient; /* коэффициент при х */
    ListNode* nextPtr;
};
```

В функцию insert я передаю две int-овые переменные coef и pow (коэффициент и степень соответственно)

```
void insert(listPtr* sPtr, int coef, int pow) {

    listPtr newPtr; /* указатель на новый узел */
    listPtr previousPtr; /* указатель на предыдущий узел */
    listPtr currentPtr; /* указатель на текущий узел */

    newPtr = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if (newPtr != NULL) {
        newPtr->coefficient = coef;
        newPtr->power = pow;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        /* цикл для поиска нужной позиции в списке */
        while (currentPtr != NULL && pow > currentPtr->power) { /* здесь вызывается исключение */
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if (previousPtr == NULL) { /* вставить новый узел в начало списка */
            newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
            *sPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else {
            previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Не удалось выделить память под новый узел!" << endl;
}
```

Вот беда: в строке `while (currentPtr != NULL && pow > currentPtr->power)` у меня вызывается следующее исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Объясните, пожалуйста, где я успела ошибиться в коде (не сильно исправляя код Дейтлов :D) и почему вызвалось исключение (честно говоря - что оно значит?).**
Код полностью:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode {
    int power; /* степень при х */
    int coefficient; /* коэффициент при х */
    ListNode* nextPtr;
};

typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
typedef struct ListNode* listPtr;

/* прототипы функций для списка (пока только две)*/
void insert(listPtr * sPtr, int coef, int pow); /* вставка в список */
int print(listPtr); /* печать списка */

int main() {
    
    listPtr startPtr;
    insert(&startPtr, 4, 3);
    insert(&startPtr, -2, 5);
    print(startPtr);
    return 0;
}

void insert(listPtr* sPtr, int coef, int pow) {

    listPtr newPtr; /* указатель на новый узел */
    listPtr previousPtr; /* указатель на предыдущий узел */
    listPtr currentPtr; /* указатель на текущий узел */

    newPtr = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if (newPtr != NULL) {
        newPtr->coefficient = coef;
        newPtr->power = pow;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        /* цикл для поиска нужной позиции в списке */
        while (currentPtr != NULL && pow <= currentPtr->power) {
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if (previousPtr == NULL) { /* вставить новый узел в начало списка */
            newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
            *sPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else {
            previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Не удалось выделить память под новый узел!" << endl;
} 

int print(listPtr sPtr){
    if (sPtr == NULL) {
        return 0; /* список пуст! */
    }
    else {
        cout << "Список: " << endl;
        while (sPtr != NULL) {
            cout << sPtr->coefficient << "x^" << sPtr->power << " + ";
            sPtr = sPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `main` :

```
int main() {
  listPtr startPtr;
  insert(&startPtr, 4, 3);
```

переменная `listPtr startPtr;` ничем не инициализирована. При старте программы этот указатель может быть заполнен случайными значениями (мусором памяти). А вы проверяете на нулевой указатель : `currentPtr != NULL` в функции `insert`. Если случайно попадается не нулевой указатель происходит неправильный доступ к памяти.

Задайте начальное значение, и будет всё стабильно.

```
  listPtr startPtr = nullptr ;
```